# How can I get some contextual data in my sink

Tags: c#, serilog

I am trying to write a custom sink that will write log entries to an internal system when the log event is related to a message on our message bus. Is it possible to attach and retrieve this data from either the log event or the log context?

```
public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
{
    //How to get this?
    MyMessageBusType correlatedMessage = null;
    if(correlatedMessage != null)
    {   
        var logMessage = logEvent.RenderMessage(formatProvider);
        internalSystemClient.WriteLog(correlatedMessage, logMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: A LogEvent has a .Properties. you can feed stuff in with Enrichers and/or LogContext.PushContext ?

Comment: @RubenBartelink yes, I have looked a bit at the `Properties`-dictionary, but the return type only has a public method to Render it to a TextWriter, which does not help very much in my case.

Comment: Ah, they are `ScalarValue`s etc. I don't have any C# code to hand, but there's a 5% chance that https://github.com/jet/CallPolly/blob/dbc466a369ab9495d45b1eff6bca5fa9c0ac3fbe/tests/CallPolly.Core.Tests/Infrastructure.fs#L124 will give you a leg up on understanding how to type check-pattern match down the hierarchy. The bottom line is that there is an object model in Serilog.Events which defines the structure - tit's all pretty well-structured. I'd suggest looking in the serilog/serilog code to infer anything you need